# How to access Value of Field name "PricePerRate" from list view

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Here is my List view code I want to Caluculate Discount based on the value diplayed on 'PricePerRate' field.

Here is my List view code I want to Caluculate Discount based on the value diplayed on 'PricePerRate' field.

```
                <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="5" Border="1" Style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; width: 300px; height: 100px; border: solid 2px #7B4F9D; background-color: white;">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell BackColor="#7B4F9D">
                       <p style="text-align:center;"> <span class="name">
                             <%# Eval("ItemName") %></span></p>

                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tcell">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Size :" CssClass="lbol"></asp:Label><span class="city">
                                <%# Eval("Sizes") %> </span>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Colour :" CssClass="lbol1" /><span class="city">
                                <%# Eval("Colour") %> </span>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Thickness :" CssClass="lbol2" /><span class="city">
                                <%# Eval("Thickness") %> </span>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Pack :" CssClass="lbol3" /><span class="city">
                                <%# Eval("Pack") %> </span>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Company :" CssClass="lbol4" /><span class="manu">
                                <%# Eval("ManufacturerName") %> </span>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Price Per Rate :" CssClass="lbol5" /><span class="city">
                                <%# Eval("PricePerRate") %> </span>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Price Per Length :" CssClass="lbol6" /><span class="city">
                                <%# Eval("PricePerLength") %> </span>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 150px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtQuantity" runat="server" placeholder="Quantity" Height="20" Width="80" OnTextChanged="TxtQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 150px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDiscount" runat="server" placeholder="Discount" Height="20" Width="80" OnTextChanged="TxtDiscount_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 100px; height: 50px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTotal" runat="server" placeholder="Total" ReadOnly="true" Height="20" Width="80"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="chklbl1" style="width: 200px; height: 50px;">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkitemselect" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" Text="Add To Estimation" Height="20" Width="80" Font-Size="10" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="chklbl" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you need ?

**C#**

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in mylistview.Items) {
     float discount = ((Label)item.FindControl("Label7")).Text;
}
```

**VB**

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In mylistview.Items
            Dim discount As Single = CType(item.FindControl("Label7"), Label).Text
Next
```

***p.s*** : its better to use native html table/tr/td than asp:table . . .
and `<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Price Per Rate :" CssClass="lbol5" text="<%#Bind('pricePerRate')"%> />` instead of `<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Price Per Rate :" CssClass="lbol5" ><span><%#eval()%>`